# In-app purchases Google vs. Apple. How to get exactly the same conversion rates so prices match across two platforms?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I am facing the following problem.

I am developing an app for both the iOS as well as the Android platform. I have set my in-app purchase prices to be exactly the same, specified in US dollars.

Now here is the problem.

When the prices get converted to another currency, because the user is in another country, the conversion rates of Apple are different from Google.

This brings an unfair disadvantage to iOS versus Android users, as one user may pay more/less for the same purchase, just because s/he is making use of another device.

Is there a way to make the conversion rate to be exactly the same across both platforms? I understand that on iOS we need to follow the pricing tier matrix, so in this case I would think that Google will have to follow the iOS prices. How can I accomplish this?